# Compiling OpenGL ES 2.0 for ARM Mali on Ubuntu

Tags: opengl-es, compilation, arm, gpu

I'm really asking for some help, at least to be pointed in the right direction. I'm working with a drone, the Parrot Bebop, which features a ARM Mali 400 GPU. I would like to be able to use such GPU for some image processing, for example, to correct the image provided by the fisheye camera, or things like that. The project is based on Paparazzi, and I use Ubuntu to program and compile, with an arm cross-compiler. What should I do to compile OpenGL ES 2.0 (which is supported by the GPU) programs on my platform? I understand I must obtain the GLES libraries for the ARM GPU but I don't know where to find them, or what to do.

Thank you for your help,

Davide

Comment: This seems dangerously close to being an off-topic resource request. It's not my area of expertise, but I'd imagine http://malideveloper.arm.com/ is well worth having a good look round to see if you can turn up enough info to make a more focused question out of.

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not mean to do an off-topic question, but I could not be more specific simply because I did not have enough information! In any case, your suggestion pointed me in the hopefully right direction, I've compiled the library for the arm GPU, thank you!

Comment: Great! Since most of the related questions seem to be related to Android/iOS, it might be useful to have a Q&A about doing it for a Linux target without a full prepackaged SDK. Feel free to add your own answer detailing exactly what you needed to do, and perhaps reword the question a bit in light of the answer to focus on the "What do I need... and how do I use..." angle rather than the "Where could I find..." one.